# Create list of lists where some values are fixed and one varies

Tags: r, lapply

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I think shouldn't be that difficult.  I want to create a list of lists like the `finalList` example below, where the `y` and `z` values are fixed and the `x` value comes from the values in the `InputList`.  If I was passing in all three `x`, `y`, `z` values then I think I'd just use something like `lapply`, but having the two values fixed and only passing in the one value is giving me a hard time.

Example:

```
InputList <- list(p=1, q=2, v=4)
finalList <- list(list(x=1, y=2, z=3), list(x=2, y=2, z=3), list(x=4, y=2, z=3))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
InputList <- list( p = 1, q = 2, v = 4 )
lapply( InputList, function( x ) list( x = x, y = 2, z = 3) )

str( lapply( InputList, function( x ) list( x = x, y = 2, z = 3) ) )
# List of 3
# $ p:List of 3
# ..$ x: num 1
# ..$ y: num 2
# ..$ z: num 3
# $ q:List of 3
# ..$ x: num 2
# ..$ y: num 2
# ..$ z: num 3
# $ v:List of 3
# ..$ x: num 4
# ..$ y: num 2
# ..$ z: num 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map()`.  The `y` and `z` values will be recycled the length of `InputList`.

```
Map(list, x = unname(InputList), y = 2, z = 3)
```